# Combobox to retain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have a textbox which is being used as a combobox when using the following code:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    $('#<%=txtCatToUpdate.ClientID %>').combobox({
        webServiceMethodName: Magelia.WebStore.Admin.Scripts.Services.AutoCompleteServices.GetCategoriesFull,
        additionalWebServiceParameter: ['<%=this.Page.UnitOfWorkContext.StoreId.ToString() %>'],
        objectIdGetter: 'CategoryId',
        labelGetter: function (o) { if (o != null) { return o.CatalogCode + ' > ' + o.CategoryCode } },
        valueGetter: function (o) { if (o != null) { return o.CatalogCode + ' > ' + o.CategoryCode } },
        hiddenField: $('#<%=hfCatToUpdateId.ClientID %>')
    });
});
```

My problem is that if the category does not exists, it gets cleared. It shouldn't get cleared. Could anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: Could you post your final html dom structure , also create a jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net